# What is "Default applications for LXSession" in Lubuntu 13.10?

Tags: lubuntu, 13.10

Users of **Lubuntu 13.10** will notice a new entry in `Menu, Preferences` called `Default applications for LXSession`.

[image: Menu, Preferences]

If that entry is selected, a window, shown below, opens:

[image: Default applications for LXSession]

This window, which can also be invoked by running `lxsession-default-apps` from a terminal has several tabs and each tab has several features.

How are these features used? Some are obvious, others aren't.

- `man lxsession-default-apps` has nothing:

  [10:48 AM] ~ $ man lxsession-default-apps
  No manual entry for lxsession-default-apps
  See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
  [10:48 AM] ~ $
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/lxsession-default-apps just mentions that it is a "*utility to configure lxsession and its default applications*"
- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy?searchtext=lxsession-default-apps draws a blank.
- the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SaucySalamander/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu) don't mention it.
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Setup#Applications has nothing.
- I looked at the mailing list and found [a mention](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-September/005577.html):

  > lxsession seems to not handle properly the migration to saucy for
  >   autostarted stuff. You can look at **lxsession-default-apps**, under
  >   autostart, and change the settings for disable autostart to no. It
  >   will force a revert to the previous behavior, until I properly fix the
  >   migration.
  >
  > Regards, Julien Lavergne

Does anyone know more about `Default applications for LXSession` and how it is to be used?

Comment: Lubuntu users may want to read this: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-November/006185.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it showed up as my first result in a Google search for "lxsession defualt application names" so I thought I might at least post something in case other folks end up here for the same reason.

My version does not have the "Running applications" tab but the "Launching applications" tab is where you specify which program will be used for common tasks (web browsing, checking email, writing documents, etc.). For example, if your keyboard has a button that should open a web browser it is here that you set which browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.) it should open.