# Desktop Session Settings not saved

Tags: lubuntu, autostart

So I am one of those people who just moved from XP to [L]ubuntu. I am used to being able to control whether programs autostart, and assumed checking or unchecking the Desktop Session Settings (from the Preferences menu) would act the same way. My changes, however, are not saved. ... Does anybody know how to control which programs/processes autostart?

Answer (score 2):

**LXSession configuration** offers you the ability to choose which applications you want to autostart. If you go to **Preferences** -> **Default applications for LXSession** -> **Autostart** you can find a list of known applications which you can enable/disable to autostart. Or you can add your own *unknown* applications using the **Manual autostarted apllications** add button.
This configuration can also be brought up by running `lxsession-default-apps`.

Comment: For more info on this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362263/what-is-default-applications-for-lxsession-in-lubuntu-13-10